# eliminate chars from cell in matlab

Tags: matlab, date, cell-array

I have a vector of all Dates from 2015, i.e.:

```
'01.01.2015'
'02.01.2015'
.
.
.
'31.12.2015'
```

How do I eliminate the days out of the list? so that the result is a list like this:

```
'01.2015'
'01.2015'
.
.
.
'12.2015'
'12.2015'
```

Thank you a lot! Additionally, it would be a great help first, if i knew, how to eliminate the days from one date. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dates are always going to be in the same format you can do it with a simple [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) call:

```
testdates = {'01.01.2015';'02.01.2015';'03.01.2015';'04.01.2015'};

myrange = [1:2 6:10];
newdates = cellfun(@(x) x(myrange), testdates, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Which returns:

```
newdates = 

    '01.2015'
    '02.2015'
    '03.2015'
    '04.2015'
```

`cellfun` applies some function to each cell in a cell array. What I use it for here is to create a new array using the indices of `myrange` applied to each cell. Note that this is not a robust methodology and will break as soon as your date format changes.

For a more robust approach you could consider using [`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) and [`datestr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html):

```
testdates = {'01.01.2015';'02.01.2015';'03.01.2015';'04.01.2015'};

serialdates = datenum(testdates, 'mm.dd.yyyy');
newdates = datestr(serialdates, 'mm.yyyy');
```

Which returns:

```
newdates =

01.2015
02.2015
03.2015
04.2015
```

This will also break if your date format changes (or varies across the array), but the behavior is more explicit than the `cellfun` call.

Comment: it doesn't work the way using the cellfun. as i want to get newdates, an error occurs. Error: Unexpected MATLAB expression

Comment: @luliusCaesar Posting an error without code is useless. Please edit your question.

Comment: I just used your cellfun call. Everything was exact the same as you did it.

Comment: @luliusCaesar if it was the exact same as I did it you wouldn't receive an error.

Answer (score 2):

Since all your strings are of the same format, you can select the characters starting from the 4th character in every string until the last character:

```
DatesCell = {'01.01.2015';'02.01.2015';'21.12.2015'}

NewDates = cellfun(@(x) x(4:end),DatesCell,'uni',0)
```

This code uses `cellfun`, which is only a for loop in disguise.

The following is equivalent:

```
DatesCell = {'01.01.2015';'02.01.2015';'21.12.2015'}

NewDatesLoop = cell(numel(DatesCell),1);
for k =1:numel(DatesCell)

    NewDatesLoop{k} = DatesCell{k}(4:end);

end
```

Output:

```
NewDates = 

    '01.2015'
    '01.2015'
    '12.2015'


NewDatesLoop = 

    '01.2015'
    '01.2015'
    '12.2015'
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't even notice I was looking at the dates wrong.

Comment: it doesn't work the way with your cellfun function. I always get the Error: Unexpected MATLAB expression

Comment: this is likely a typo. Please show the code you used. What about the for loop?